Prove the principle of strong recursion and apply it to the definition of the factorial function.
I need help solving this exercise: Prove the principle of strong recursion and apply it to the definition of the factorial function.
I have attempted to solve it and am presenting the definitions mentioned in the text, along with my attempt at a proof.
Definitions:
1.- $I_n=\{0,…,n\}$,
2.- If $A$ is a set, then $A^*$ is the set of all functions $h:I_n\rightarrow A$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$,
3.- If $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow A$, then $f_n:I_n\rightarrow A$.
Principle of Strong Recursion:
If $A$ is a set, $a\in A$ and $g : A\times A^∗\rightarrow A$, there exists a unique function $f : \mathbb {N} \rightarrow A$ such that for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$:
$f(0)=a, f(n+1) = g(f(n),f_n)$.
Attempt at a Proof:
We define the function $h:I_{n} \rightarrow A$ as an approximation if it satisfies the following conditions:
1.- $h(0)=a$,
2.- $h(m+1)=g(h(m),h|_{I_m})$ for all $m < n$
In this way, two approximations coincide in the common part of their domains. Specifically, if $n\leq m$ and the domains of the approximations $h,h^*$ are $I_n, I_m$, respectively, then they must agree on their shared domain.
If they do not coincide, there must exist a smallest $i+1\in \mathbb N$ where $h(i+1)\not=h^*(i+1)$. Thus,
$h(i+1)=g(h(i),h|_{I_i})=g(h(i),h^*|_{I_i})=h^*(i+1)$,
which leads to a contradiction. The choice of $i+1$ is valid because it is evident that when evaluating any approximation at $0$, it always equals $a$.
Next, we prove by induction that for every $m\in \mathbb N$ there exists an approximation $h:I_m\rightarrow A$:
Base case ($m=0$): The function $h:{0}\rightarrow A$ defined by $h(0)=a$ is an approximation by definition.
Inductive step: Suppose $h:I_m\rightarrow A$ is an approximation. We then define $h^*:I_{m+1}\rightarrow A$ as the function that coincides with $h$ on $I_m$ and satisfies $h^*(m+1)=g(h(m),h)$. By construction,
$h^*(m+1)=g(h(m),h)=g(h^*(m),h^*|_{I_m})$.
Finally, we define $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow A$ as $f(0)=a$, $f(n+1)=h(n+1)$, where $h$ is any approximation that includes $n+1$ in its domain. Since all approximations coincide on their common domains, $f$ is well-defined. In particular, $f_{n}=h|{I_n}$, so
$f(0)=a=h(0)$ and $f(n+1)=h(n+1)=g(h(n),h|{I_n})=g(f(n),f_n)$.
Uniqueness follows because if another function $f^*$ satisfied the same conditions but $f\not= f^*$, there would exist a smallest $n+1\in \mathbb N$ such that $f(n+1)\not= f^*(n+1)$. However,
$f(n+1)=g(f(n),f_n)=g(f^*(n),f^*_n)=f^*(n+1)$,
which is a contradiction.
The Factorial Function:
The factorial function is defined as $!:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ by
$0!=1$, $(n+1)!=n!\cdot(n+1)$.
Attempt to Apply the Principle of Strong Recursion to the Factorial Function:
Define $g:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N^*\rightarrow \mathbb N$ as $g(h(n),h_n)=n\cdot h^*_n(h_n)$, where $h^*_n$ is the function that determines the maximum of the domain of $h_n$, which is always $n$. Therefore,
$g(h(n),h_n)=h(n)\cdot n$.
This allows us to define a unique function $f=!$, such that $0!=1$ and $(n+1)!=g(f(n),f_n)=n!\cdot n$.
Main Question
I believe the proof of the principle of strong recursion is correct, but the application of this principle to the factorial function does not convince me. This is because I had to define a function $h^*: \mathbb N^* \rightarrow \mathbb N$ that determines the maximum of $h_n$ for any $h_n \in \mathbb N^*$.
